# Drawing lines on top of bar chart using ggplot (Box and Whisker kind)

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to draw the following:
Given a bar chart in ggplot similar to this one: a grouped bar chart, flipped over x axis.

I would like to draw a line on top of each of the bars. The longitude of the line is defined in the dataframe df2. (think about it as some sort of standard deviation)

The longitude of the line is defined, and it will be centered at the highest point of each bar.
As you can see this is not similar to a boxplot, it is a line that will always remain constant and centered on top of each bar.

So I was wondering if it was possible to do this with the code I am showing in the next Section. In excel it is quite fast to do this using what is called a Box and wisker plot. The final result should look like the following:

[image]

This is the code I am currently using, hope someone can please help me out.

```
df <- read.table(
text = 
"group metric somevalue
T1 epsilon 63
T2 epsilon 91
T1 kappa 19
T2 kappa -3
T1 zulu  -5
T2 zulu 8", header=TRUE)

str(df)

df$metric <- factor(df$metric, levels = c("kappa", "zulu", "epsilon"))

df2 <- read.table(
text = 
"group metric deviation
T1 epsilon 20
T2 epsilon 10
T1 kappa 10
T2 kappa 20
T1 zulu  25
T2 zulu 10", header=TRUE)

thePlot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=metric, y=somevalue, fill=group)) + geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') + coord_flip() + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), legend.position="bottom",
       legend.text=element_text(size=14),
       legend.title = element_blank(),
       axis.title.x = element_blank(),
       axis.title.y = element_blank())+ 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#CC6600", "steelblue")) + ylim(-20, 100)
thePlot
```

[image]

Update: Notice that something using geom_errorbar() will have to make use of different error confidence intervals, each confidence interval is actually in the df2 dataframe. So this is like a dinamic drawing, line by line on top of bar chart by bar chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use 'geom_errorbar' which will flip when 'coord_flip' is called as well.

An example from my own data is here:

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Rmisc)

group_data <- summarySE(data = Data_P_L, measurevar = "w", groupvars = c("Median_Age_Split","Stake"))


ggplot(data = group_data, aes(x = Median_Age_Split, color = Stake, fill = Stake)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = Median_Age_Split, y = w), 
           position= "dodge", color = "black", alpha = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = Median_Age_Split, ymin=w-ci, ymax=w+ci), position=position_dodge(.9),
                width = 0.2, size = 1, color = "black") +
  theme_light()
```

[image: flipped bar chart]

```
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = Median_Age_Split, y = w), 
           position= "dodge", color = "black", alpha = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = Median_Age_Split, ymin=w-ci, ymax=w+ci), position=position_dodge(.9),
                width = 0.2, size = 1, color = "black") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_light()
```

Comment: is there any way I can have the sample dataframe Data_P_L, I would like to see the inner workings. thanks!

Comment: in my case "ci" changes in each bar. :(

Comment: the confidence interval should change each bar, as this depends on the category for each bar. by specifying ymin = value - ci and ymax = value + ci, you plot the 95% confidence interval error bars. You can also use 'se' if you want the standard error of the mean.